# How to correctly initialize a state array React JS

Tags: reactjs

I need to initialize a state array with six elements, points, and then update the proper element in the points array when setVote function is called:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
const setNextItem = (value) => setSelected(value)
const initialValue =  new Array(6).fill(0);
const [points, setPoint] = useState(initialValue)
const setVote = (value) => setPoint(value)

// randomly choose the next item
const setNextitem(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0))

const setVote => {            
    const copy = [...points]
    copy[selected] += 1 
    return copy;
}
```

However, when I view points and copy arrays in the console window, points never gets updated with copy. It stay as Array(6) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]. Is it always initializing or is the copy array not retuned. What is the correct way to do this?

Here is my final code:

````
```
const App = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(new Array(6).fill(0))
    const setNextItem = (value) => setSelected(value)  
    const setVoteAt = (value) => setPoints(value)
    console.log(selected, points)

const next_button = {
    name : 'next item',
    onClick: () => setNextItem(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0))
}
const vote_button = {
    name : 'vote',
    onClick: () => setVoteAt(UpdatePoints(selected))
}

const UpdatePoints = (index) => {
    let copy = [...points]
    copy[index]++
    return copy
}
```
````

Comment: I'm not quite sure what `setVote` does as it is defined twice. Did you mean to name the last function something else?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I will try these out and let everyone know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Too many duplicated function and state

Just a little order the code..

react useState is not rective, then you can do useEffect to console.
And then you will see the update array.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState(new Array(6).fill(0));

const UpdatePoints = (selected) => {
  let copy = [...points];
  copy[selected]++;
  setPoints(copy);
}

const random = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)

useEffect(() => console.log(points))

return (
  <div onClick={() => UpdatePoints(random())}> ClickMe </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work for the most part. I'd say these two functions are conflicting, and causing an issue. Are there any errors returned in the console?

```
const setVote = (value) => setPoint(value)
const setVote => {            
    const copy = [...points]
    copy[selected] += 1 
    return copy;
}
```

This last one you may want to rename. Something like `setVoteAt` which take an index parameter for which vote to set.

```
const setVoteAt = (index) => {            
    const copy = [...points]
    copy[index] += 1 
    return copy;
}

setVoteAt(2) // [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to correctly initialize a state array React JS

Use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to initialize it properly. This is similar to `componentDidMount`.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState([])

useEffect(() => 
  {
    const initialValue =  new Array(6).fill(0);
    setPoints(initialValue);
  }
, []) // initialize only once (on mount) and not on every render
```

> Is it always initializing or is the copy array not retuned. What is the correct way to do this?

`setVote()` is not doing things correctly. You can update `points` every time `selected` is changed by:

```
useEffect(() => 
  {
    setPoints(points => {
      points[selected] += 1
      return points
    })
  }
  , [selected] // only run this effect every time selected changed
)

setNextItem(2) // this will update selected then run the effect on top
               // and also increment points[selected]
```